# If MX records are set to Gmail, does the mailbox need to exist in the CPanel hosting package?

Tags: gmail, mx, email-address

I have a client who currently has his domain's MX records set to Gmail `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.`, etc.

I am transferring the client's site to a new host.

Do I need to create the mailbox in the new host's CPanel? Or is mailbox management and creation managed by Googlemail, so nothing will change if I update the A Name?

Please confirm the existing email's will be not lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the MX records override this and instead mail goes direct to google servers.
You do not need to create cpanel email accounts.

You should have A records pointing to your cpanel server where the site resides and the MX records to google servers as you correctly stated earlier.